# Heroku - hosting a static website on a react node application

Tags: heroku

I have a react application hosted on Heroku and I made a static html landing page in a different project.

I'm tryiing to set it up so when I go to the url:
myreactapp.herokuapp.com the static html page will show up

While when I go to:
myreactapp.herokuapp.com/link/1
My working react application will load.

How do I approach this? Do I use the react router? The node backend router? Or is it an Heroku configuration issue?

Thanks.

Comment: sorry if this is a silly question, but are you serving your static html page from a node server you wrote, that's deployed on heroku?

Comment: I could do that if that helps me solve my issue. Currently the home page is ready and the app is ready and I haven't uploaded the home page yet